# code triggered a breakpoint but I set no breakpoint at all

Tags: c++, visual-studio, breakpoints

I was running a very simple program in MS visual studio 2015 and set NO breakpoint at all, but the output is:

> XXXX.exe has triggered a breakpoint.

I did not set any breakpoint at all. Why would this happen? Thanks.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
int a = 1;
int b = a + 1;

cout << "b is " << b << endl;

getchar();
return 1;
}
```

Actually the code works in cpp.sh, so I believe it must have something to do with visul studio setting

updates:
I find the exact same problem here:
https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-visual-fortran-compiler-for-windows/topic/590210#comment-1844444
I also installed the intel compiler. The code runs in debug-x64 mode but not debug-x86 mode. However, I could not add any breakpoints in either mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is still certain incompatibility between intel and MS visual studio. I uninstalled intel stuff from visual studio and now it works.

Answer (score -1):

I think you returning a 1 might cause the system to think its a failure, try either returning a 0, or doing void main() and remove the return statement.

Comment: try removing getchar(); and replace with cin >> a;

Comment: When you created the project did you select a blank console application?
Try to do a simpler app that just shows hello world and see if that causes a breakpoint

Comment: Well someone else was having this issue with getchar();
http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/155298/
if a simple hello world app crashes then repair your visual studio using add/remove programs.

Comment: Don't do `void main`!  It's not a valid signature for main.  You always return `int`.  In C++ there's the special case that you don't have to actually write a return statement in main and it'll return 0.  You must still return `int`.