# Why does my MPI application trigger a breakpoint?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, mpi, breakpoints

I have a simple MPI application that is used to pass values from process 0 to other processes upon entering the desired value but it is triggering a breakpoint on "else".

What am I missing?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "mpi.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int rank;
    int value;
    int size;

    MPI_Status status;
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

    do
    {
        if (rank == 0)
        {
            printf("Enter the value: ");
            scanf_s("%d", &value);
            MPI_Send(&value, 1, MPI_INT, rank + 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        }

        else
        {
            MPI_Recv(&value, 1, MPI_INT, rank - 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, 
                     &status);
            
            if (rank < size - 1)
                MPI_Send(&value, 1, MPI_INT, rank + 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        }

        printf("Process %d got %d ", rank, value);

    } while (value >= 0);
    
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

This is output from debug:

> 'MPIHelloWorld.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>
> 'MPIHelloWorld.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\gdi32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>
> 'MPIHelloWorld.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Bonjour\mdnsNSP.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>
> MPIHelloWorld.exe has triggered a breakpoint.
>
> MPIHelloWorld.exe has triggered a breakpoint.
>
> The thread 0x3308 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
>
> The thread 0x1dfc has exited with code 0 (0x0).
>
> The thread 0x2e5c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
>
> The program '[4400] MPIHelloWorld.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

UPDATE:

When I press CTRL + 5 I get this error written in my console:

job aborted:
[ ranks ] message

[0] fatal error
Fatal error in MPI_Send:
Invalid rank has value 1 but must be nonnegative and less than 1

Comment: are you debugging it?

Comment: @Mgetz yes, I am

Comment: did you set a breakpoint at the `MPI_Send`?

Comment: @Mgetz no, I havent...the app just breaks from console and a breakpoint appears right next to the else

Comment: have you checked the debug output panel to see what it says? Bets are you're causing an exception

Comment: please append that to your question, don't post it in the comments

Comment: Sorry, it's my 2nd time using StackOverflow :) I have added the output.

Comment: I'm thinking you set the breakpoint yourself accidentally

Comment: @Mgetz There are no breakpoints. I have tried CTRL+SHIFT+F9 to delete all breakpoints just in case.

Comment: @Klim [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33204314/code-triggered-a-breakpoint-but-i-set-no-breakpoint-at-all) might be useful.

Comment: I don't understand what the issue is - it looks like correct program so why are you debugging it? When I compile and run on my laptop the only issue is that the screen output doesn't appear until the end - it's all OK if you put carriage returns on your prints. I also had to replace scanf_s with scanf.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I have finally found an answer!

I couldn't use Cluster Debugger for MPI since I am running Visual Studio 2015
and the problem was that only 1 process was running.

I opened CMD and ran my application using "mpiexec.exe -n 4 myMpiApp.exe" and it worked.